# how to findfolders then subfolders and then print filenames in alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco

I am new to alfresco. I need to loop the folders to the subfolders and files contained in the respective folders so that action taken on the parent folder must also be displayed on the sub folders.The method has to be called recursively but I am no getting any clue how to proceed further.

Do guide me in this. Thanks..

Comment: This isn't an example of a recursive method call. You have the `executeImpl` method that seems to start things but the loop function would need some sort of recursion in a different method.

Comment: So we cannot perform the recursive action in the executeImpl method? By just creating one more "for loop" for the folder?

Comment: That depends on how deep your folder structure is. If you know the exact depth then maybe, but it would be really ugly and hard to read.

Comment: Need to implement for nth depth. Can you help me in this?

Comment: See my answer below. I did just make an edit to fix a bug I missed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as though you are having problems with understanding how to create a recursive operation for your folders. I'll try to give you an example of how I would handle this. Given my example may not be the best.

```
public static final String NAME = "Demo-Folder";
public static final String PARAM_ASPECT_NAME = "folder-name";
private NodeService nodeService;
/**
 * Set the node service
 *
 * @param nodeService  the node service
 */
public void setNodeService(NodeService nodeService)
{
    this.nodeService = nodeService;
}

public void executeImpl(Action action, NodeRef actionUponNodeRef)
{
    ChildAssociationRef childAssociationRef = nodeService.getPrimaryParent(actionUponNodeRef);

    System.out.println("****The folder is***** "+ childAssociationRef);
    iterateThroughChildren(childAssociationRef);
}

public void iterateThroughChildren(ChildAssociationRef childAssocRef)
{
    System.out.println("****The folder is***** "+ childAssocRef);
    NodeRef childNodeRef = childAssocRef.getChildRef();
    List<ChildAssociationRef> children = nodeService.getChildAssocs(childNodeRef);

    for (ChildAssociationRef childAssoc : children) 
    {
       childAssoc.getChildRef();
      // Use childNodeRef here.
      System.out.println("******Documents inside are******"+ childAssoc);

      // This call recurses the method with the new child.
      iterateThroughChildren(childAssoc);
      // If there are no children then the list will be empty and so this will be skipped.


    }
}
```

I used your code above, and extended it out to include a new method called `iterateThroughChildren` which takes the `ChildAssociationRef` and gets the children and iterates through them. During the iteration the children are passed back into the method to allow for their children to be iterated, and so on until there are no children (meaning you are at the end of a branch). This allows you to iterate through an entire tree structure.

Comment: I see it, another bug from copy/paste of your code. Hold on I'll fix it. Basically the first two lines of `iterateThroughChildren` were using variables that didn't exist inside the method. Sorry about that. See the edit for my correction.

Comment: Getting error "The method getChildAssocs(NodeRef) in the type NodeService is not applicable for the arguments (ChildAssociationRef)" for the line  List<ChildAssociationRef> children = nodeService.getChildAssocs(childAssocRef);

Comment: Ah got it. Sorry not really used to Alfresco's node system. You would need to add the following `NodeRef childNodeRef = childAssocRef.getChildRef();` The problem is that the method `nodeService.getChidAssocs()` requires a `NodeRef` and not a `ChildAssociationRef`. Again this is because I'm not familiar with Alfresco.

Comment: Thanks a lot... This has been a huge help will get back to you in case of further clarifications.

Comment: Hmm, you would probably have to add some sort of counter. That could be a class field that only increases when the iterateThroughChildren is called.